# How can I know if my Chrome Extension is called from a New Tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension has a popup with a few links, which I would like to be opened in the current tab if it's a New Tab page, or open in a new tab otherwise. So I believe I need to know the active tab's URL. Or is there another way to identify a New Tab?

I'd like to use the "activeTab" permission rather than "tabs" - I want the user to see as few permissions listed as possible.

The only way I've found to identify the tab's URL is by using a background page and

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab))
```

But this is not compatible with having a popup defined in the manifest. I can set the popup page programatically, but I can't see a way to make the popup appear. Is there a way to do that?

When I have default_popup defined in the manifest I use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ())
```

to launch the related code, so no reference to the active tab is available. Is there another way to run the code, or to get the active tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission allows you to "Get the URL, title, and favicon for that tab via an API that returns a `tabs.Tab` object". So, to get the current tab URL from the popup you can do:

```
chrome.tabs.query( {active:true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Comment: How frustrating! I had some similar code hours ago, but I was using the console to view the URL, and it was being reported as "undefined". When I inject the URL string into the popup page it always shows what you'd expect. It's only when I add the "tabs" permission that the console reports the correct URL! Thanks for your help.